# Can i search for links inside MSOffice documents in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search

DocumentID  is enabled and in my site collection i have a multiple link references to particular document. This links are pasted as link into Word documents.  Is there any way to configure sharepoint search to look up a DocumentID as keyword inside office documents?

Answer (score 0):

There is a managed property with the name DocId and the Query property should be enabled.  The property should be mapped to the crawled property ows_dlc_DocId.

You can search using the following keyword to search your document:
*`DocId:value`*

A blog about this topic for your reference:
[Search By Document ID In SharePoint 2013](https://richardstk.com/2014/12/12/search-by-document-id-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Comment: Thanks, Kally.  Actually, i don't need to search for a document  by DocId. I need to search for a link to the document  with DocId as a part of the URL inside other documents.

Comment: SharePoint do a full content index, it will crawl all content of a document as text, if you search using docid, it will return the document which contains the link with docid. You can have a try.